# ASP.NET Core WebApi. OData configuration for SQL Views

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

I am facing an error with OData configuration.

I have a Rest API in ASP.NET Core 2.2 using EntityFrtamework to communicate with Oracle Database (only Views).
Now, I am trying to configure OData in my project and I don`t know exactly how I can create OData endpoint to get data from View. How can I create EDM model for View (without key) to configure ODAta endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create Edm Model for SQL View (without key), then you can use this code:

```
private IEdmModel GetEdmModel(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
   var edmModel = new ODataConventionModelBuilder(app.ApplicationServices, true);

   edmModel.EntitySet<Student>("Students");
   return edmModel.GetEdmModel();
}
```